# How to search for questions with at least 1 answer?

Tags: discussion, search

After typing a user's ID, what must be typed to search for all such user's questions with **at least** 1 answer? So I ask NOT about `answers:1`.

Answer (score 3):

I think `user:(id) answers:1..` will do it for you. And maybe add `is:question` depending on exactly what you're after.

Take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching for all the operators. Or, you can use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) if SQL is your thing.